# How to write a query in LINQ inside a SSIS Component that returns an object property

Tags: c#, linq, ssis

I wanted to write a script to discover, for each airline, which class is First, Business and so on.

The first thing i do is pulling the matching from a database's table that looks like this:

[image: Sample table values here]

```
public HashSet<CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia> _classe;
public ICollection<CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia> ElencoClassi
{
    get
    {
        //Explicit Lazy-pattern
        if (_classe == null)
        {
            _classe = new HashSet<CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia>();
            using (var cnn = (SqlConnection)Connections.Reporting.AcquireConnection(null))
            using (var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
            {
                //Set the query here

                //only load from the db what you really need
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID_Compagnia, ID_Classe, Classe FROM [dbo].[DIM_ClassiCompagnie]";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //start the query. it actually opens a server side cursor on sql server
                var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    _classe.Add(new CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia()
                    {
                        ID_Compagnia = dr["ID_Compagnia"].ToString(),
                        ID_Classe = dr["ID_Classe"].ToString(),
                        Classe = dr["Classe"].ToString()
                    });
                }

            }
        }
        return _classe;
    }
}
```

Then in the script's main i invoke the following method:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    var classi = ElencoClassi;
    Row.Classe = TrovaClasse(Row.CodiceCompagnia, Row.ClasseVettore, classi);        
}

static string TrovaClasse(string ID_Compagnia, string ID_Classe, IEnumerable<CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia> classi)
{
    var q = (from c in classi
             where c.ID_Classe.Equals(ID_Classe) && c.ID_Compagnia.Equals(ID_Compagnia)
             select c).FirstOrDefault<CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia>();

    if (q != null)
    {
        return q.Classe.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "ND";
    }
}
```

Row.CodiceCompagnia is a string that can be something like "220" and Row.ClasseVettore is a string that contains the class' letter like "J"

However, for some reason, i get ND on every attempt. So i'm starting to believe that something must be wrong in the query since otherwise var q should be equal to an object like

{ ID_Compagnia = "220", ID_Classe = "J", Classe = "Business" }

And shouldn't just be null.

Any ideas?

/EDIT:

I tried to have something like that working on a console program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ColonneInput Input = new ColonneInput { ID_Comp = "220", ID_Class = "X" };
        CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia ec = new CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia { ID_Compagnia = "220", ID_Classe = "X", Classe = "Business" };

        var InputColonne = new List<ColonneInput>() { Input };
        var ElencoClassi = new List<CategoriaTariffePerCompagnia>() { ec };
        //LINQ Query
        var q = (from c in ElencoClassi
                from i in InputColonne
                where (c.ID_Classe == i.ID_Class) && (c.ID_Compagnia == i.ID_Comp)
                select c.Classe).FirstOrDefault();

        if (q == null)
        {
            q = "Sconosciuta";
        }




        Console.WriteLine( q.ToString() );
        Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to stop");
        do
        {
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
```

And it works! So now it seems that there is some kind of problem with the creation of the big object "ElencoClassi"...

Comment: if you take the first part of your where clause out, `c.ID_Classe.Equals(ID_Classe) &&`, does that work? You'll be performing a case sensitive comparison here so a j wouldn't match a J. If it still doesn't produce a result, take out the where clause entirely and verify you are getting results

Comment: If i do that i get:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
That's so strange since there IS an object there!

Comment: When I'm writing anything more than a trivial bit of .NET in SSIS, I find it's best to create a separate C# project, something like a Console App, and get all my code working there with the rich debugger experience. *Then* move my logic back into SSIS and simply wire up the invocation

Comment: It's what i did too!

Comment: I figured out that if i manually assign values in the TrovaClasse() method adding, just before the LINQ query, ID_Compagnia = "220" and ID_Classe ="J". Everything works (of course it returns "Business" for every entry but it's intended!). So there must be some issue with the input columns...